# Getting General error : '"mysqldump"' is not recognized as an internal or external command in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Getting General error : '"mysqldump"' is not recognized as an internal or external command in laravel while run the following command.

```
php artisan backup:run
```

I did this in config/database.php file

```
 'dump' => [
    'dump_binary_path' => 'C:/xampp/mysql/bin/', // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`
    'use_single_transaction',
    'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
 ],
```

but no success still getting the same error. please help!

Comment: are you sure `mysqldump.exe` exists on that path?

Comment: yes i just checked its there!

Comment: That doesn't look like a Windows path, right?  I've never seen a `dump` config in the database config before.  Some searching suggests you are using [laravel-backup from Spatie](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-backup/v6/installation-and-setup/)?  You would make it simpler for ppl t help if you mention such key details.  Anyway, a simple search for "laravel-backup spatie Windows" [turns up this issue](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup/issues/311) which clearly described the Windows-format path required when specifying the bin path.

Comment: yeah... I actually never seen this command before. It's even not listed at my `php artisan list`. Is this built in? Or it's from another composer package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updaded like this-

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'dump' => [
            'dump_binary_path' => 'C:\xampp\mysql\bin' // only the path, so without `mysqldump` or `pg_dump`

         ],
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'modes' => [
            //'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', // Disable this to allow grouping by one column
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
        ],
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. I set the correct path in environment variables but got stuck. I replace the extension name with .sql and it works.

database/schema/mysql-schema.sql
This works on my end.